# SPSS adds a random "discrete missing values" for numeric variable altered from string

Tags: syntax, spss

I altered string variables to numeric; SPSS added a random "discrete missing values" for them (as in screen shot below). What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Rebekah Wickens

I am not sure how you get this strange missing value for your numeric variable.
I suggest you just delete it with the short syntax command below:

```
MISSING VALUES income_current_539f0f ().
```

The empty bracket will delete the current discrete missing value in the variable income_current_539f0f.